# simplenews sent newsletter to all user not subscribing categroies with taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, emails

I used a simplenews module to send user news, in user registeration I add field in user registeration refer to a A vocab ( list of some favorites)(as a name **field_favourites**) and user can select his favorite(s) from favorites category in registeration,

In Also in **admin/structure/types/manage/simplenews/fields** add that field again (**field_favourites** field that refer to favorites Vocab) .

**The problem is when I create simplenews , and select one or some categories ,module email for all user not user that subscribe only for selected category(s),Where is the problem?**

**anybody know how can I achieve this job ? sending news only and only for user that subscribed for that category in user registeration ?**